# anchor build error: got target is not supported

Tags: rust, anchor, solana

Problem
When i try to run anchor build, i get the following error:

```
error: target is not supported, for more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#unsupported-targets
   --> /Users/mac/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/getrandom-0.1.16/src/lib.rs:267:9
    |
267 | /         compile_error!("\
268 | |             target is not supported, for more information see: \
269 | |             https://docs.rs/getrandom/#unsupported-targets\
270 | |         ");
    | |___________^

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
   --> /Users/mac/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/getrandom-0.1.16/src/lib.rs:292:5
    |
292 |     imp::getrandom_inner(dest)
    |     ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imp`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
error: could not compile `getrandom` due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Environment:

solana-cli 1.8.13 (src:42c3fbc1; feat:1006352700)

rustup 1.24.3 (ce5817a94 2021-05-31)

rustc 1.61.0 (fe5b13d68 2022-05-18)

anchor-cli 0.24.2

Comment: when run cargo build-bpf , I had the same problem .  Just running it with cargo build is no error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are including a dependency in your anchor project that uses the rng which is not available on bpf. Usually this is a result of trying to include a cryptographic package in your on-chain program.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and this works for me based on this https://docs.rs/getrandom/0.2.6/getrandom/macro.register_custom_getrandom.html.
from cargo.toml:

```
getrandom = { version = "0.2", features = ["custom"] }
```